# Keyboard shortcut to replace middle mouse-button

Tags: xorg, openbox

Unfortunately my middle mouse-button is broken. Is it possible to define a keyboard shortcut that'll do the same thing as the middle mouse-button (paste text from XA_PRIMARY)? (I'm using openbox for managing my windows.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the "`Shift + Insert`" key bindings for most applications.
If you install the `xdotool` command, you can also send a click event on the command line.

```
$ xdotool click 2
```

Comment: Great, sending click events from the command line, now I can bind this to a keyboard shortcut. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way create the binding such that the mouse button is _down_ while either shift or insert are pressed? I'm in a similar situation, and found that Blender can treat `ALT` presses this way, but I can't seem to figure out how to make that universal

Comment: @J-Cake Do you mean something like `printf 'keydown shift\n click 1\n keyup shift\n' |xdotool -` ?

Comment: actually almost. I'm looking for a solution which would let me drag with the middle mouse down. So, for the duration that the shortcut is active (all keys are down), the system treats the mouse wheel as depressed.

Comment: @J-Cake Perhaps `xdotool mousedown 2` and `xdotool mouseup 2` will help. In any case, I suggest posting it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks. I think I might...